# When using (flexlayout) column, div isn't correct size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have 4 `li's` with a `div` having a background image (through `CSS`). I'm using `flexbox` for the layout. I want it to have columns with 3 `li's` in each column. Everything is working fine besides for the `div` containing image. The height of the `div` is larger than its parent.

The weird thing is, when I make it into `rows` instead of `columns`, it has the correct height.

(If it shows the correct size by you, then try making the windows width wider.)

How can I make the `div` to have the correct size?

#### JSFiddle

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";

    function resizeHeightLi() {
        $('li').css('height', 'calc(' + $('li').width() + 'px / 1.8)');
    }

    resizeHeightLi();

    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizeHeightLi();
    });

});
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color:aqua;
}
ul {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    flex-basis: 70%;
    height: 80%;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /*flex-direction: row; // When it's set to row, it works fine.*/
    flex-direction: column;
}
li {
    
    flex-basis: calc(100% / 3 - 2px); /* Subtract the border */
    color: firebrick;
    list-style-type: none;
    
    border: 1px solid firebrick;
}
.image {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/nswXRR4.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><div class="image"><span>1</span></li>
        <li><div class="image"><span>2</span></li>
        <li><div class="image"><span>3</span></li>
        <li><div class="image"><span>4</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the height of each `li` is taken care of by your `flex-basis` rule in the CSS, I think there is no need to assign the height again with JavaScript. Instead, you can get the height of each `li` after the flex calculations are done and assign it to your image divs. That way, both parent and child elements are the same height.

```
function resizeHeightLi() {
    $('.image').css('height', $('li').height() + 'px');
}
```

**EDIT (CSS Only)**

To accomplish the same purely with CSS, you can delete all the JS you have now and add the following to your CSS:

```
// In addition to what you already have in your li
li {
  // ...
  position: relative;
}

// Same here, in addition to what you have in .image
.image {
   // ...
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That's sort of a hack. Is there any other way?

Comment: I agree, overall I don't think you need to resize using javascript, but just let the CSS flex do all the resizing for you. See edit above, note that for it to work you need to delete the JS stuff you have now.